# JCheckBox doesn't trigger isselected

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcheckbox

I have a JPanel, which contains a JPanel and a JButtons.
in the inner JPanel I have some JCheckBoxes which are initially selected. I have added an actionListener to  my JButtons that check, if each of the JCheckBoxes changed to unselected an action performs.
but It doesn't work. this is my code, where would the problem be?

```
public LimitPanel(String[] dates, int column) {

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1 + dates.length, 0);
    setLayout(layout);
    setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    setVisible(true);

    this.dates = dates;

    checks = new JCheckBox[dates.length][column-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < column - 1; j++) {
            checks[i][j] = new JCheckBox();
            checks[i][j].setSelected(true);
            checks[i][j]
                    .setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            add(checks[i][j]);

        }
    }
}
public JCheckBox[][] getChecks() {
    return checks;
}
```

in my Main Clas, I have another method that contains:

```
ResultSet e = connect.select("Invi", "*");
        try {
            while (e.next()) {
                final int inviID = e.getInt("inviID");
                    JPanel pn = new JPanel();
                pn.setSize(d.width, d.height);
            pn.setLocation(0, 0);
                    pn.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pn, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

                    lp = new LimitPanel(st, 6);
                    pn.add(lp);



                    JButton sabt = new JButton("  ثبت  ");
                    sabt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                            System.out.println("saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabt");
                            JCheckBox[][] jcb = new JCheckBox[lp.getDates().length][5];
                            jcb = lp.getChecks();
                            for (int i = 0; i < lp.getDates().length; i++)
                                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                                    if (!jcb[i][j].isSelected()) {
                                        System.out.println("naaaaaaaaa");
                                        connect.insertLimit(inviID, (lp
                                                .getDates())[i], j+"");
                                    }

                                }

                        }
                    });
                    pn.add(sabt);

                    panels.add(pn);

                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            setContentPane(panels.get(p));
            revalidate();
```

I edited it to contain what ever is necessary, my problem is that `System.out.println("saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabt");` is always works when I press the button but what ever I do with the checkBoxes `System.out.println("naaaaaaaaa");` never works.

Comment: In `for (int j = 0; j < column - 1; j++) {` it should be `j < collumn` or `j <= collumn -1`. You'r skipping a whole row of JCheckBoxes in this loop.

Comment: the problem insists, I have a checkbox with column-1 columns. I have written here incorrectly. I will edit it.

Comment: You get your checkboxes from `lp` which is a `LimitPanel` which in turn is initialized with `st`. I won't even going to ask what the `st` variable is. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so you can get help faster

Comment: Where's the `getChecks` method?  You shouldn't be passing back the `JCheckBox`, it exposes it to possible modification.  Instead, you `lp` class should provide a `isChecked` method instead - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer getchecks is a method I added it to my question. it doesnt return boolean, it returns the JChceckBoxes Value.

Comment: @c.s. `st` is an array which is correctly initialized, but the process is so long so that I decided not to post it.to make sure I have tested both of my classes, and they work properly individually but together no.

Comment: @Paniz I was pretty sure it did (return `JCheckBox[]`), my suggestion would be to change it, again, because you are exposing objects that can be modified out side of your control.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added what ever is necessary and removed what ever is extra. I don't know what else I should do :(

Comment: Code snippets are not compilable & therefore not 'correct' at showing (being an example of) the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using a `while` (`while (e.next()) {`) to build portions of your program.  Within it your a creating a new reference to `lp` and `JButton`, `sabt`, on each iteration.

Your `ActionListener` will only be able to reference the LAST instance of `lp` created.  This is most likely why you `actionPerformed` is doing what you think it should be...

Think about it like this...if I do...

```
lp = new new LimitPanel(st, 6);
lp = new new LimitPanel(st, 6);
lp = new new LimitPanel(st, 6);
lp = new new LimitPanel(st, 6);

JCheckBox[] = lp.getChecks();
```

Which instance of `lp` have I obtained the check boxes from??

**Updated with more details**

```
// Create a new instance of "LimitPanel"
lp = new LimitPanel(st, 6);
// You can check this by using the hashCode of the object...
System.out.println(lp.hashCode());
pn.add(lp);

JButton sabt = new JButton("  ثبت  ");
sabt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        /*...*/
        // Use what ever was last assigned to "lp"
        jcb = lp.getChecks();
        // You can check this by using the hashCode of the object...
        System.out.println(lp.hashCode());
        /*...*/
    }
});
```

IF you really wanted to ensure that the `ActionListener` was using a particular instance of `LimitPanel`, you should pass that reference to a special instance of `ActionListener`...

For example...

```
lp = new LimitPanel(st, 6);
// You can check this by using the hashCode of the object...
System.out.println(lp.hashCode());
pn.add(lp);

JButton sabt = new JButton("  ثبت  ");
sabt.addActionListener(new LimitActionHandler(lp));
```

And the `LimitActionHandler`...

```
public class LimitActionHandler implements ActionListener {

    private LimitPanel limitPane;

    public LimitActionHandler(LimitPanel limitPane) {
        this.limitPane = limitPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        /*...*/
        // Use what ever was last assigned to "lp"
        jcb = limitPane.getChecks();
        // You can check this by using the hashCode of the object...
        System.out.println(limitPane.hashCode());
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

As I stated in my comments, I think it's a bad idea to expose the `JCheckBox`es from the `LimitPanel`, as it allows other parts of your application unrestricted access to those objects, which they don't need for there work...

```
JCheckBox[] jcb = limitPane.getChecks();
for (JCheckBox cb : jcb) {
    cb.setSelected(false); //...
}
for (JCheckBox cb : jcb) {
    cb.getParent().remove(cb); //...
}
```

This is very dangerous.  You can argue that your application won't do these things, but you can't stop it from happening...

Comment: I have an `actionlistener` for each `Limit1panel` . I think each one should work for its own. no?

Comment: No, you don't have one for each `ActionListener`.  Each `ActionListener` is referencing the last instance of `lp` you created...

Comment: @trashgod Me or the OP?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Just a link for your reference; +1 for trying, but I was at a loss. Paniz: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod Ah, I see.  Double posting...naughty Paniz

Comment: @MadProgrammer: To be fair, Paniz deleted the question after I deleted my answer; `getChecks()` remains a mystery, and I remain wary of passing around arrays of components.

Comment: @trashgod Paniz posted the `getChecks()` method and I've commented (at least twice) about the wisdom of passing `Components` about in this manner as well.  Totally agree

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your complete answer. I will do what ever you said to fix the problem.

Comment: @Paniz Let me know if you have issues getting the concept to work ;)

Comment: @trashgod ya I have asked it before, but after changing it I didn't get any answer so I decided to post it once again. sorry any how and thanks for your help.